# Woocommerce how to sort product attributes in category listing?

Tags: sorting, foreach, woocommerce

```
<?php
foreach ($variations as $variation) 
{
    $supersize = $variation["attributes"]["attribute_pa_sizes"];
    $variable_id = $variation['variation_id'];?> <span class="SIZES"><?php echo $supersize ;?></span>
```

So, i'm at a little deadend here. I'm using Woocommerce and the product attributes are sorted by CUSTOM SORTING, but in the front-end i call the attributes via the code provided above. 
Now, i want to be able to sort the $supersize by the custom ordering.

What should i write or what idea do you have so that i can sort the attributes provided via foreach argument. Newbie question :(

Thanks!

Comment: Why not use `$variation->get_variation_attributes()`?

Comment: Well, i need the variations to be displayed and not the attributes.  When a variation is out-of-stock i just delete it, so it disappears. If i get the attributes, then i have to delete the variations and the attribute.  So, if on a product the S size is out-of-stock then i delete the variation and it is gone. If i show the attributes, then i have to delete the variation S and the attribute S.